# How to create binary tree from level order traversal?

Tags: python, binary-tree

Given a `level_order` list, which can include `None` values, how can a binary tree be constructed adhering to `None` values in the list i.e `None` nodes can't have any children (`left` or `right` values).

```py
from typing import List, Optional

class Node():
    def __init__(val: int=None, left: Optional[Node]=None, right: Optional[Node]=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def binary_tree(level_order: List, root=None): -> Node:
    pass
```

For example, when `level_order` is `[4, -7, -3, None, None, -9, -3, 9, -7, -4, None, 6, None, -6, -6, None, None, 0, 6, 5, None, 9, None, None, -1, -4, None, None, None, -2]`, the tree should look like this [image]

And when the `level_order` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the tree should look like [image]

The following code generates binary tree while not respecting the `None` values in the list

```py
def binary_tree(level_order, root=None):
    ls = []

    def insert_value(data, root):
        newnode = Node(data)
        if len(ls) != 0:
            temp = ls[0]

        if root is None:
            root = newnode

        elif temp.left is None:
            temp.left = newnode

        elif temp.right is None:
            temp.right = newnode
            _ = ls.pop(0)

        ls.append(newnode)
        return root

    for i in range(len(level_order)):
        root = insert_value(level_order[i], root)

    return root
```

But the above code results in the following incorrect tree
[image]

Comment: @cs95 Added my existing code for the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you get a level-order list of nodes from a tree in the first place? Well, you return every element from a breadth-first traversal of the tree. To rebuild the tree from a level-order list, then, we can traverse the tree in a breadth-first way.

When we insert each element, starting with the root, add it to a queue. Then, once we finish adding both the left and right children of a node, pull the next node from the queue. Once we run out of elements to add, just return the root.

```
from typing import List, Optional

class Node():
    def __init__(self, val: int=None, left: Optional['Node']=None, right: Optional['Node']=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def binary_tree(level_order: List) -> Node:
    values = iter(level_order)
    root = Node(next(values))
    nodes_to_fill = [root]
    try:
        while True:
            next_node = nodes_to_fill.pop(0)
            new_left = next(values)
            if new_left is not None:
                next_node.left = Node(new_left)
                nodes_to_fill.append(next_node.left)
            new_right = next(values)
            if new_right is not None:
                next_node.right = Node(new_right)
                nodes_to_fill.append(next_node.right)
    except StopIteration:
        return root
```

This is the same mechanism as breadth-first search would use, except in this case we're using it to *construct* the tree, rather than to *search* it.

For slightly more efficiency, if your tree is very large, you could probably use a `queue.Queue` instead of a list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the approach. I like the idea of taking the next two values (`new_left` and `new_right`) and updating the `nodes_to_fill` based on the value.