# Getting Leaf Nodes From a Binary Tree

Tags: php, data-structures

I am learning and practicing BinaryTree Data Structure in PHP following [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/) I read online.

Right now in my script I want to insert nodes from an array and then determine all the leaf nodes.

Still haven't grasped this concept quite yet and when I run my code I run out of memory.  So just to be clear I want to be able to add values to my binary tree and later traverse it and return a list of all leaf nodes.

This is what I've tried soo far:

```
<?php

class Node
{

    public $value;
    public $left;
    public $right;

    public function __construct($item)
    {
        $this->value = $item;
        $this->left = null;
        $this->right = null;
    }
}

class Tree
{

    protected $root;

    public $leafs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->root = null;
        $this->leafs = [];
    }

    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return $this->root === null;
    }

    public function insert($node)
    {
        if ($this->isEmpty()) {
            $this->root = $node;
        } else {
            $this->setNode($node, $this->root);
        }
    }

    protected function setNode($node, &$subTree)
    {
        if ($subTree === null) {
            $subTree = $node;
        } else {
            if ($subTree->left == null) {
                $this->setNode($node, $subTree->left);
            } else if ($subTree->right == null) {
                $this->setNode($node, $subTree->right);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getLeafs()
    {
        if ($this->root !== null) {
            if ($this->root->left == null && $this->root->right == null) {
                array_push($this->leafs, $this->root->value);
            } else {
                $this->getLeafs($this->root);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}

$tree1 = new Tree();
$items1 = [3, 5, 1, 6, 2, 9, 8, null, null, 7, 4];

foreach ($items1 as $item) {
    $node = new Node($item);
    $tree1->insert($node);
}

$tree2 = new Tree();
$items2 = [3, 5, 1, 6, 7, 4, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, 9, 8];

foreach ($items2 as $item) {
    $node = new Node($item);
    $tree2->insert($node);
}

print_r($tree1->getLeafs()->leafs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three main problems: 1) `insert`/`setNode` don't work the way you probably think they do, and 2) they're the wrong paradigm for how your input is set up, and 3) `getLeafs()` doesn't iterate correctly.

The way `insert` usually works (which you've partially implemented in `setNode`) is checking if the value you want to insert is higher or lower than the current node's value, then recursively going left or right depending.

What you have is a check that the root's left or right children are null, and inserting into the first null you find. That will never recurse once the root and its left and right children are non-null.

But the way your input is structured is different from that input pattern entirely. You're not inputting them one by one at the root, instead you're inserting in level order.

So instead you want a level-order insert instead, which tracks which node is 'current' and adds two children to it from the input queue.

For example, input `[3 5 1, null, null, 6]` means a tree like

```
     3
   /   \
  5     1
       /
      6
```

Where you create the node for `3`, then create `5` and add it to `3`, then `1` and add it to `3`, etc. See these for the algorithm: [How to construct a binary tree using a level order traversal sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754060/how-to-construct-a-binary-tree-using-a-level-order-traversal-sequence), [How to create binary tree from level order traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190919/how-to-create-binary-tree-from-level-order-traversal)

Then, for `getLeafs`, you do not iterate correctly (and you don't even have an input parameter).

What you need is more like this,

```
    public function getLeafs($current)
    {
        if ($current !== null) {
            if ($current->left == null && $current->right == null) {
                array_push($this->leafs, $current->value);
            } else {
                $this->getLeafs($current->left);
                $this->getLeafs($current->right);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Note how `getLeafs` now takes a parameter `$current`, and when it is called recursively, it is called with `$current->left` and `$current->right`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I understood your explanation and checked the examples but seeing as their not in PHP i'm a bit confused, not getting it for some reason.

Comment: Also is this the right situation for me to be using level order insert or have I made a mistake?